# WinJS Repeater Only Binding First Property

Tags: windows, repeater, winjs

I have a list of objects with two properties, and I want my repeater to display each of them. The first property should be inside an `<h2>` tag, and the second should be in an `<h3>` tag.

HTML:

```
<div class="dataColumns" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Repeater">
  <h2 data-win-bind="textContent: Title"></h2>
  <h3 data-win-bind="textContent: SomeOtherProperty"></h3>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var columnData = new WinJS.Binding.List([
        { Title: 'First Title', SomeOtherProperty: 'First SomeOtherProperty' },
        { Title: '2nd Title', SomeOtherProperty: '2nd SomeOtherProperty' }]);

document.querySelector('.dataColumns').winControl.data = columnData;
```

Here is the actual output, as seen in the DOM Explorer:

```
<div class="dataColumns win-repeater win-disposable" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Repeater">
  <h2 class="win-disposable">First Title</h2>
  <h2 class="win-disposable">2nd Title</h2>
</div>
```

**Why is only the `<h2>` shown for each item?**

Here is what I would have expected:

```
<div class="dataColumns win-repeater win-disposable" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Repeater">
  <h2 class="win-disposable">First Title</h2>
  <h3 class="win-disposable">First SomeOtherProperty</h3>
  <h2 class="win-disposable">2nd Title</h2>
  <h3 class="win-disposable">2nd SomeOtherProperty</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Repeater` template may have only one direct descendant element (like in the case below, a single child `div`:

```
<div class="dataColumns" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Repeater"         >
    <div>
        <h2 data-win-bind="textContent: Title"></h2>
        <h3 data-win-bind="textContent: SomeOtherProperty"></h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Results:

[image: Results]

You may also consider using a `WinJS.Binding.Template` for the contents of the `Repeater`:

```
<div class="template" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div>
        <h2 data-win-bind="textContent: Title"></h2>
        <h3 data-win-bind="textContent: SomeOtherProperty"></h3>        
    </div>
</div>
<div class="dataColumns" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Repeater" 
     data-win-options="{template: select('.template')}">

</div>
```

Comment: Note that the HTML Repeater control sample (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HTML-Repeater-control-da22d278) shows some nested binding scenarios that might be helpful here.